# Issue with data display and constructor

Tags: c++, class, object, constructor

I have a problem with understanding constructor and this is causing me problem while displaying data with string name and string position. the first character of name and position are removed and initialized with " " (space).

please ignore any indentation problems etc because this is my first time posting here...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


class Employee
{
    private:
        string name ; // for employee's name
        int id ;      // for employee's id number
        string department ;  // for name department
        string position ; //for position employee holds

    public:

        Employee()  // constructor
        {
            name = " " ;
            id = 0 ;
            department = " " ;
            position = " " ;
        }

        Employee ( char a , int i )
        {
            name = a ;

            id = i ;

            position = " " ;

            department = " " ;

        }

        Employee ( char a , char b , char c , int i )
        {
            name = a ;

            id = i ;

            department = b ;

            position = c ;


        }

        Employee ( const Employee &obj )
        {
            name = obj.name ;

            department = obj.position ;

            position = obj.position ;

            id = obj.id ;

        }

        int set_Name( char a )
        {
            name = a ;

            return 0;

        }

        int set_Id( int i )
        {
            id = i ;

            return 0;

        }

        int set_Position( char b )
        {
            position = b ;

            return 0;

        }

        int set_Department( char d )
        {
            department = d ;

            return 0;
        }



        string get_Name( void ) const
        {
            return name ;

        }

        int get_Id( ) const
        {
            return id ;

        }

        string get_Position( void ) const
        {
            return position ;

        }

        string get_Department( void ) const
        {
            return department ;

        }



        int set_Info( char a , char b , char c , int i )
        {
            name = a ;

            id = i ;

            department = b ;

            position = c ;

            return 0;
        }

        void get_Info ()
        {
            cout << endl  << " Enter Employee name =  " ;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin , name);

            cout << " Enter id number of employee = " ;
            cin >> id ;


            cout << " Enter Employee department = " ;
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin , department);

            cout << " Enter Emloyee position in company = ";
            cin.ignore();
            getline(cin , position);


        }

        void put_Info(  )
        {
            cout << "Employees info : - " ;
            cout << "   " << name << "   "  << id << "   " << department << "   " << position << endl ;

        }

        ~Employee()
        {
            cout << " destructor executed .... " ;
        }

};


int main()
{

    Employee obj1 , obj2 , obj3 , obj4 , obj5 ;

    obj1.get_Info();
    obj2.get_Info();
    obj3.get_Info();
    obj4.get_Info();
    obj5.get_Info();

    cout << endl;

    obj1.put_Info();
    obj2.put_Info();
    obj3.put_Info();
    obj4.put_Info();
    obj5.put_Info();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are using `char` as the argument type for many of your function instead of `string`. Did you mean that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `cin >> name;` or `cin >> department;` before `cin.ignore();`

You can remove `cin.ignore()` when you use `getline` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20970780/getline-cin-ignore-in-c)